# ESP32 DEVKITV1 - Can't generate waves in two cores

Tags: pwm, esp32, multicore

I'm using a ESP32 (DEVKITV1) to generate two waves in two different cores. Below is the code I'm using.

```
#define Num_Samples  112
#define MaxWaveTypes 4

// Defining wave types to be generated
int i = 0;

static byte WaveFormTable[MaxWaveTypes][Num_Samples] = {
   // Sin wave
   { 
    0x80, 0x83, 0x87, 0x8A, 0x8E, 0x91, 0x95, 0x98, 0x9B, 0x9E, 0xA2, 0xA5, 0xA7, 0xAA, 0xAD, 0xAF,
    0xB2, 0xB4, 0xB6, 0xB8, 0xB9, 0xBB, 0xBC, 0xBD, 0xBE, 0xBF, 0xBF, 0xBF, 0xC0, 0xBF, 0xBF, 0xBF,
    0xBE, 0xBD, 0xBC, 0xBB, 0xB9, 0xB8, 0xB6, 0xB4, 0xB2, 0xAF, 0xAD, 0xAA, 0xA7, 0xA5, 0xA2, 0x9E,
    0x9B, 0x98, 0x95, 0x91, 0x8E, 0x8A, 0x87, 0x83, 0x80, 0x7C, 0x78, 0x75, 0x71, 0x6E, 0x6A, 0x67,
    0x64, 0x61, 0x5D, 0x5A, 0x58, 0x55, 0x52, 0x50, 0x4D, 0x4B, 0x49, 0x47, 0x46, 0x44, 0x43, 0x42,
    0x41, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x41, 0x42, 0x43, 0x44, 0x46, 0x47, 0x49, 0x4B,
    0x4D, 0x50, 0x52, 0x55, 0x58, 0x5A, 0x5D, 0x61, 0x64, 0x67, 0x6A, 0x6E, 0x71, 0x75, 0x78, 0x7C
   },
   // Triangular wave
   {
     0x80, 0x84, 0x89, 0x8D, 0x92, 0x96, 0x9B, 0x9F, 0xA4, 0xA8, 0xAD, 0xB2, 0xB6, 0xBB, 0xBF, 0xC4,
     0xC8, 0xCD, 0xD1, 0xD6, 0xDB, 0xDF, 0xE4, 0xE8, 0xED, 0xF1, 0xF6, 0xFA, 0xFF, 0xFA, 0xF6, 0xF1,
     0xED, 0xE8, 0xE4, 0xDF, 0xDB, 0xD6, 0xD1, 0xCD, 0xC8, 0xC4, 0xBF, 0xBB, 0xB6, 0xB2, 0xAD, 0xA8,
     0xA4, 0x9F, 0x9B, 0x96, 0x92, 0x8D, 0x89, 0x84, 0x7F, 0x7B, 0x76, 0x72, 0x6D, 0x69, 0x64, 0x60,
     0x5B, 0x57, 0x52, 0x4D, 0x49, 0x44, 0x40, 0x3B, 0x37, 0x32, 0x2E, 0x29, 0x24, 0x20, 0x1B, 0x17,
     0x12, 0x0E, 0x09, 0x05, 0x00, 0x05, 0x09, 0x0E, 0x12, 0x17, 0x1B, 0x20, 0x24, 0x29, 0x2E, 0x32,
     0x37, 0x3B, 0x40, 0x44, 0x49, 0x4D, 0x52, 0x57, 0x5B, 0x60, 0x64, 0x69, 0x6D, 0x72, 0x76, 0x7B
  },

   // Sawtooth wave
   {
     0x00, 0x02, 0x04, 0x06, 0x09, 0x0B, 0x0D, 0x10, 0x12, 0x14, 0x16, 0x19, 0x1B, 0x1D, 0x20, 0x22,
     0x24, 0x27, 0x29, 0x2B, 0x2D, 0x30, 0x32, 0x34, 0x37, 0x39, 0x3B, 0x3E, 0x40, 0x42, 0x44, 0x47,
     0x49, 0x4B, 0x4E, 0x50, 0x52, 0x54, 0x57, 0x59, 0x5B, 0x5E, 0x60, 0x62, 0x65, 0x67, 0x69, 0x6B, 
     0x6E, 0x70, 0x72, 0x75, 0x77, 0x79, 0x7C, 0x7E, 0x80, 0x82, 0x85, 0x87, 0x89, 0x8C, 0x8E, 0x90,
     0x93, 0x95, 0x97, 0x99, 0x9C, 0x9E, 0xA0, 0xA3, 0xA5, 0xA7, 0xA9, 0xAC, 0xAE, 0xB0, 0xB3, 0xB5,
     0xB7, 0xBA, 0xBC, 0xBE, 0xC0, 0xC3, 0xC5, 0xC7, 0xCA, 0xCC, 0xCE, 0xD1, 0xD3, 0xD5, 0xD7, 0xDA,
     0xDC, 0xDE, 0xE1, 0xE3, 0xE5, 0xE8, 0xEA, 0xEC, 0xEE, 0xF1, 0xF3, 0xF5, 0xF8, 0xFA, 0xFC, 0xFE
   },
   // Square wave
   {
     0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff,
     0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff,
     0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff,
     0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
     0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
     0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
     0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00
   }
};


// Implementing tasks in separated cores


TaskHandle_t Task1;
TaskHandle_t Task2;



void setup() {
  Serial.begin(460800); 


  //create a task that will be executed in the Task1code() function, with priority 1 and executed on core 0
  xTaskCreatePinnedToCore(
                    Task1code,   /* Task function. */
                    "Task1",     /* name of task. */
                    10000,       /* Stack size of task */
                    NULL,        /* parameter of the task */
                    1,           /* priority of the task */
                    &Task1,      /* Task handle to keep track of created task */
                    0);          /* pin task to core 0 */                  
  delay(500); 

  //create a task that will be executed in the Task2code() function, with priority 1 and executed on core 1
  xTaskCreatePinnedToCore(
                    Task2code,   /* Task function. */
                    "Task2",     /* name of task. */
                    10000,       /* Stack size of task */
                    NULL,        /* parameter of the task */
                    1,           /* priority of the task */
                    &Task2,      /* Task handle to keep track of created task */
                    1);          /* pin task to core 1 */
    delay(500); 
}

//Task1code: generate square wave 
void Task1code( void * pvParameters ){

  for(;;){
  //byte wave_type = 0; // Sine
  //byte wave_type = 1; // Triangle
  //byte wave_type = 2; // Sawtooth
  byte wave_type = 3; // Square
  dacWrite(25, WaveFormTable[wave_type][i]); 
  i++;
  if (i >= Num_Samples) i = 0; 
  } 
}

//Task2code: generate another square wave
void Task2code( void * pvParameters ){


  for(;;){
  //byte wave_type = 0; // Sine
  //byte wave_type = 1; // Triangle
  //byte wave_type = 2; // Sawtooth
  byte wave_type = 3; // Square
  dacWrite(26, WaveFormTable[wave_type][i]); 
  i++;
  if (i >= Num_Samples) i = 0; 
  }
}

void loop() {
  
}
```

The code compiles just right, but when I use an oscilloscope to see the waves, they're all messed up,like in the pic below[image: oscilloscope]

I don't know what's happening. I'm new to ESP32 and I didn't write all the code, just modified it from these two url (https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp32-dual-core-arduino-ide/) and (https://www.instructables.com/ESP32-Do-You-Know-What-DAC-Is/). My doubt is whether these noisy waves are a problem of my code or my board doesn't have much processing power to generate two waves.

Comment: Processing power has nothing to do with it. There is no processing. Do you use the very same DAC to output two signals at the same time?

Comment: @llya No, I'm using two different pins....25 and 26....both of them have noisy signals. Oh, and I'm also using the ground pin correctly, because I can generate one single wave when using one core.

Comment: I didn't ask if you're using the same pin. Are you using the same DAC? DAC is a device inside MCU - a peripheral. It can be connected to different pins on the outside. If you use one DAC device to output two different values to two different pins at the same time, you're in trouble.

Comment: @llya Sorry, I didn't read your comment correctly...there is two DACs in the board, located at pins 25 and 26...both of them are 8-bit

Comment: I have opened a pinout of ESP32 DEVKIT 1, and there is no pin 26. UPD: found one with pin 26 somewhere far below. they're all devkit 1, but they're all different.

Comment: Did you try to output only one waveform? Also, your picture is pretty bad, I can't really see anything specific in it. I can't even tell if there is 1 or 2 waveforms in your picture. (The pins are indeed connected to two different DACs)

Comment: @llya The pic is very bad indeed, sorry for bad resolution.....but there is supposed to have a train of square waves....but, in fact, there is only a messy squared wave, that keeps flashing and appearing noisy in the oscilloscope(like in the pic)....I tried to output just one wave using one core and worked fine.

Comment: Did you try only one thread? Try each of them individually and alone. Try each of them alone on each core, if that's possible. Just to rule out basic stuff.

Comment: @llya Tested both cores here, individually. Core 0 is working fine (few noise although). Core 1 is messed up, keeps phasing my wave and has a lot of noise.

Comment: This one will be hard to find. Could be something about initialization of multithreaded system, could be something in errata. Might require deep dive into registers and debugging. Sounds fishy and complicated. Unfortunately, can't help much more, never had an ESP32. But you know where to start to dig. Something related to the core. Thread bring up or DAC working with that core problem. Still, check MCU's errata just in case.

Comment: @llya how can I access the errata?

Comment: Internet search. https://espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/eco_and_workarounds_for_bugs_in_esp32_en.pdf check the table of contents. Also, check whatever section 3.18 leads to. It may be something, it may be nothing. It's just a good idea to check if there is anything in errata related to your problem. Usually it's not, but it guarantees you're not fighting against silicon bug. Like checking that TV is plugged into the wall before taking it to repair.

Comment: @llya found it, thanks for your help :)

Comment: Both tasks share the same variable "i". This is an interesting fight between them.